# read Excel sheet with linq- skip duplicated id

Tags: c#, excel, linq, linq-to-excel

In following excel file, I need to read rows as `Student` class which define single object for the unique ID and then get all exams associated with this student.

[image]

If I used the following code I generate number of students equal to number of rows and without specifying exams list for each object student.

```
IQueryable<Student> Students_var;

var  excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileName_global1);
excel.AddMapping<Student>(x => x.ID, "STU_NO");
Students_var = from c in excel.Worksheet<Student>("Stu_Schedule")
                select c;
List<Student> StudentList_c = Students_var.ToList();
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/linqtoexcel/y4eVTp_wQjU/Ffp2sMDEohQJ

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified a your questions in order to have a working unit test.

I'm creating the values locally instead of reading it from an excel file.

in the values that I'm creating I have 3 items but only 2 students so I'm verifying that the linq query returns always 2 records.

you can see in the below code how to group your items.

```
    [Test]
    public void LinqSelect_MultipleRowsWithTheSameId_RemoveDuplicatedRecords()
    {
        var excel = new [] {new Student() {ID = 1,Exam = 1}, new Student() { ID = 1, Exam = 2 }, new Student() { ID = 2, Exam = 1 } };
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,Student>> Students_var = from c in excel
                           group c by c.ID into newExcel
                       select newExcel;
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Students_var.ToList().Count);
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Exam { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Student class has a list of exams but I didn't mention the exact declaration

Comment: number of rows in the excel is dynamic not 2, what do you mean with this 2?
        Assert.AreEqual(2, Students_var.ToList().Count);

Comment: I've changed the Var declaration so it will be clearer that the linq expression returns your objects by grouping

Comment: my unit test just demonstrate the linq query, I'm creating the student list hard coded and query against it directly without any excel file...

Comment: it give me an exception ""LinqToExcel does not provide support for the Group() method""

Comment: Please, could you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567715/addmapping-column-to-list

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the Student ID then add each exam to the Student Object.

```
var grouped  = StudentList_c.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new Student
        {
            ID = x.Key,
            Exam = x.SelectMany(z=> z.Exam).ToList()
        }).ToList();


public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<int> Exam { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it give me an exception ""LinqToExcel does not provide support for the Group() method""

Comment: The GroupBy method is in using System.Linq;  I have edited the code to be used on the StudentList_c variable.  This should work.

Comment: Please, could you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567715/addmapping-column-to-list

Comment: Sure, I will take a look. if my answer helped please upvote.  If it answered your question about grouping your data please select it as the answer,

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = excel.Worksheet<Student>("Stu_Schedule").ToList();

var groupedStudents = rows.GroupBy(y=>y.Id)
                          .Select(x => new Student
    {
        ID = x.Key,
        Exam = x.SelectMany(z=> z.Exam).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: give me error   }).ToList(); >>> Error 1 Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'lambda expression'

Comment: Sorry about that, I dont have linq2Excel now. This is reference from my memoory.

Comment: Still give the same error for  select (x => new Student
                                     {
                                         ID = x.Key,
                                         Exam  = x.SelectMany(z => z.Exam).ToList()
                                     }).ToList();

Comment: Error 1 Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'lambda expression'

Comment: can u check now , i have updated that too, The problem was i mixed linq with lamda

Comment: Error 2 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: error on   var groupedStudents = rows.GroupBy(y=>y.ID)

Comment: sorry im not sure what exactly the issue. The group by statement is valid in syntax

Comment: Please, could you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567715/addmapping-column-to-list

Comment: I saw that , the change was you figured out like its with the `List<string>` to List<int> conversion and you dont have model of `z.Exam` in your model