# AddMapping column to list

Tags: c#, excel, linq, grouping

I have the following `Student` class, which each ID has a list of exams, I need to map the column of Exam to property of `Exams_Line_list`. The following code return empty `Exams_Line_list`

```
public class Student
    {
        string id;
        public List<String> exams_Line_list = new List<String>();
        public String exams_Line1;

        public string Exams_Line1
        {
            get { return exams_Line1; }
            set { exams_Line1 = value; }
        }

        public string ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public List<String> Exams_Line_list
        {
            get { return exams_Line_list; }
            set { exams_Line_list = value; }
        }
}
```

Reading the Excel sheet:

```
IQueryable<Student> Students_var;
var  excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileName_global1);

excel.AddMapping<Student>(x => x.ID, "STU_NO");
excel.AddMapping<Student>(x => x.Exams_Line1, "Exam");
Students_var = from c in excel.Worksheet<Student>("Stu_Schedule")
               select c;

List<Student> StudentList_c = Students_var.ToList();

var grouped = StudentList_c.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new Student
              {
                ID = x.Key,
                Exams_Line_list = x.SelectMany(z => z.Exams_Line_list).ToList()
              }).ToList();

foreach (var r in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.ID);
        foreach (String s1 in r.Exams_Line_list)
                    Console.WriteLine(s1);
}
```

Schema:

[image]

I have add a String property to map Exam column, (`Exams_Line1`)
break point `StudentList_c`
[image]

Now it read all rows including duplicate id with each exam value, but how to group them to the defined list (`Exams_Line1`)

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint before the line `var grouped = StudentList_c.GroupBy...` to check what is inside `StudentList_c`? Specifically make sure it contains correct values of Exam strings.

Comment: Yes, Question is updated

Comment: okay please see the edited version

Comment: Please check it

Comment: Where do you define the mapping of Exam column to Exams_Line1? Is that something happening by convention?

Comment: forgot to add it, now added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can just use this:

```
var grouped = StudentList_c.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new Student
{
   ID = x.Key,
   Exams_Line_list = x.Select(z => z.Exams_Line1).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Here I'm assuming that `Student_List` has all the rows corresponding to rows in excel sheet and `Exams_Line1` property is being mapped to `Exam` column.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: Exams_Line1 is string but Exams_Line_list  is list<string>

Comment: Thank you, it is saved my time :)

Comment: Select should take care of generating List<String> from String